# Why Aren't Spaces and Characters Being Removed From String?

Tags: android, string, replace, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm a noob to android and I am having issues altering a string.  I have a listview that is being populated from an arraylist.  In my OnItemClick method, I want to take the value of the selection make it lowercase, remove the spaces, and remove the apostrophes.  However, I have only been able to make the string lowercase and the space and apostrophes remain.  For instance,  "Bear's Garlic" becomes "bear's garlic" and not "bearsgarilc".  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
String herb_pic = herb_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().toLowerCase() + "_picture";
                        herb_pic.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); //Not removing whitespaces
                        herb_pic.replace(" ", ""); //Not removing space
                        herb_pic.replace("'", ""); //not removing apostrophe
                        herb_pic.replace(".", ""); //Not removing 
                        Log.e("herb_pic result", herb_pic);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in java `String`s are immutable:

```
String herb_pic = herb_ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().toLowerCase() + "_picture";
herb_pic = herb_pic.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); //Not removing whitespaces
herb_pic = herb_pic.replace(" ", ""); //Not removing space
herb_pic = herb_pic.replace("'", ""); //not removing apostrophe
herb_pic = herb_pic.replace(".", ""); //Not removing 
Log.e("herb_pic result", herb_pic);
```

Comment: So are you saying it's not possible to remove the characters and spaces?

Comment: no I am saying the herb_pic can not be modifyed "in place", but every time you perform an operation upon a String, replaceAll for instance, a new string install is returned

Answer (score 1):

Because the `replace`function returns a String where the characters have been replaced.

```
herb_pic = herb_pic.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```